# How do I change the "NA" string to actual NA for all columns in my Data?

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset with 40 columns and 9000 rows, all of the columns contain at least one string "NA". I want to drop every row that has at least one "NA" but I need to change it to an actual NA value beforehand.

I cannot use the `na.strings=""` argument as I am getting my data using the `opendatatoronto` package, not `read.csv`.

I have also tried this code, which didn't work either. `for(i in names(data)) (set(data, which(data[[i]] == "NA"), i, NA))`

Comment: You may use `df1 <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE);df1 <- df1[complete.cases(df1),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr::na_if()` should do the trick:

```
df <- tibble( x = c('A', 'NA', 'C'), 
        y = c('D', 'E', 'NA'), 
        z = c('NA', 'NA', 'I' ))

na_if(df, 'NA')
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```r
dat[dat == 'NA'] <- NA
```